# Why does my program produce multiples of my radio buttons instead of just one?

Tags: python, user-interface, radio-button

The following code I have written produces a GUI app window that allows my manufacturer to run some automation and onboarding commands at just a couple clicks of buttons instead of 1 by 1.

Where I am running into an issue is the display and action of the radio buttons. The display makes 4 of each button, so selecting one is not as it should be (see visual), therefore the actions are not in order with what the buttons do. I am wondering where i went wrong in my design of this program?

*Some values and user/password data removed for security

```
import subprocess
import tkinter, re, uuid
from tkinter.constants import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import socket, os, subprocess, multiprocessing, sys
from getmac import get_mac_address as gma
import getmac, paramiko
from tkinter import *  
import time, requests
import threading
import tkinter as tk


def pinger(job_q, results_q):
    """
    Do Ping
    :param job_q:
    :param results_q:
    :return:
    """
    DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    while True:

        ip = job_q.get()

        if ip is None:
            break

        try:
            subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c1', ip],
                                stdout=DEVNULL)
            results_q.put(ip)
        except:
            pass

def get_my_ip():
    """
    Find my IP address
    :return:
    """
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    ip = s.getsockname()[0]
    s.close()
    return ip

def map_network():
    cmd = subprocess.run(["arp", "-a"], capture_output=True)
    a = str(cmd).split(",")
    b = a[3].replace("stdout=b'", "").replace("\\n", "\n")
    #print(b)
    c=b.split("on wlan0")
    for x in c:
        print("Device: ",x)

def test_log():
    print('Mapping...')
    addresses = subprocess.check_output(['arp', '-a'])
    print(addresses)

def raspi_connecter():
    proc = subprocess.Popen('ssh dev@X.0.0.X', shell=True)
  
def serial_ssh():
    p = paramiko.SSHClient()
    p.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())   
    p.connect("X.0.0.X", port=22, username="user", password="Password!")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = p.exec_command('ls')
    opt = stdout.readlines()
    opt = "".join(opt)
    print(opt)
    input("press enter to continue")


    stdin, stdout, stderr = p.exec_command('sed -n 43p /proc/cpuinfo')
    opt1 = stdout.readlines()
    opt1 = "".join(opt1)
    print(opt1)
    input("press enter to continue")


    stdin, stdout, stderr = p.exec_command('ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -N "')
    opt17 = stdout.readlines()
    opt17 = "".join(opt17)
    print(opt17)
    input("press enter to continue")

    stdin, stdout, stderr = p.exec_command('cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')
    opt18 = stdout.readlines()
    opt18 = "".join(opt18)
    print(opt18)
    input("press enter to continue")

    stdin, stdout, stderr = p.exec_command('git clone 
    git@github.com:SpiderDoorLLC/spiderkeypadpi.git')
    opt19 = stdout.readlines()
    opt19 = "".join(opt19)
    print(opt19)
    input("press enter to continue")

def keypad_tests():
    os.system('/home/dev/commands.sh -into %d -geometry 40x20 -sb &' % wid)
       

def redirector(inputStr):
    w.insert(INSERT, inputStr)
sys.stdout.write = redirector

if __name__=='__main__':
    tk = tkinter.Tk() 
    tk.title("Manufacturing App")

    v = StringVar(tk, "1")  
    values = {"Serial_SSH" : "1", 
        "Network Device Scan" : "2", 
        "Connect Keypad" : "3", 
        "Run Automation" : "4"}

    c = StringVar(tk, "1")
    commands = {"serial_ssh" : "1",
        "test_log" : "2",
        "raspi_connecter" : "3",
        "keypad_tests" : "4"}
        
    def quit_loop():
        print ("Selection:",c.get())
    global selection
    selection = v.get()
    tk.quit()
    if selection == 1:
        print(c.get())
    elif selection == 2:
        print(c.get())

    for (text, value) in values.items():
        Radiobutton(tk, text= text,value= 1, command = serial_ssh).pack(anchor=W)
        Radiobutton(tk, text= text,value=2, command = test_log).pack(anchor=W)
        Radiobutton(tk, text= text,value=3, command = raspi_connecter).pack(anchor=W)
        Radiobutton(tk, text= text,value=4, command = keypad_tests).pack(anchor=W) 
     
            
    frame = tkinter.Frame(tk, relief=RIDGE, borderwidth=2)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=100)

    w = Text (frame, height= 20, width= 50)
    w.pack()
    
    termf = Frame(tk, height=100, width=100)
    termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
    wid = termf.winfo_id()


    button1 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Submit", command=quit_loop)
    button1.pack(side=RIGHT)
    

    tk.mainloop()
```

[visual aid for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mZZx.png)

Comment: In `for (text, value) in values.items():` you create 4 buttons each time you loop and you loop 4 times. 4 * 4 = 16.

Comment: I must be having a brain mixup, i cannot seem to figure out how to fix this with what I write? do you have an idea? I tried one button but it still does not select all 'values' in that part of the program so i tried making 4 lines of the radiobutton and here i am

Comment: The command should be a part of the datastructure. `values = {'Serial_SSH': (1, serial_ssh), 'Network Device Scan': (2, test_log), ...}`. Then in your loop you need only one line: `Radiobutton(tk, text=text, value=value[0], command=value[1]).pack(anchor=W)`. (This is untested, I didn't work with Tk for over 10 years).

Comment: worked perfectly. Thank you for your assistance! @Matthias

Comment: I was just trying to avoid my real work where I have to program in [PL/SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) - a damn ugly language. ;)